# JAXBElement generated even with generateElementProperty to false

Tags: maven, jaxb, wsdl, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I generate types in a WSDL using xjc maven plugin. Following my configuration :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auth-service-type-generation</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                        <schemaDirectory>${wsdl.location}</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaFiles>${wsdl.auth.srv.file.name}</schemaFiles>
                        <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
                        <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                        <nv>false</nv>
                        <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb/</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingFiles>jaxb_bindings.xjb</bindingFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Content of jaxb_bindings.xjb :

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I used this binding to get rid of JAXBElement but it is still generated. What's wrong in my settings or is there another way to generate types in my WSDLs without JAXBElement ?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is missing properties in your config: `schemaLocation` and `node`.

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../path/your.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
      <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: So if I have several schemas, do I have to duplicate the tag for each one ?